# A PS1 compiled to EXE does not recognize the passed parameters

Tags: powershell-2.0

Powershell Newbie here.

Using PowerGUi Script Editor, I compile a PS1 to EXE.   When I run the EXE it does not see the passed parameters.  I am running them from the PowerShell Console in the PowerGUI Script Editor.

**Here is the program code.**

```
param([string]$foo , [string]$bar , [string]$who)
Write-Host "Arg0: $foo"
Write-Host "Arg1: $bar"
Write-Host "Arg2: $who"
```

**Here are the test results**
--Calling EXE--

```
PS C:\test> .\blat2.exe it bugs me
Arg0: 
Arg1: 
Arg2:
```

--Calling PS1--

```
PS C:\test> .\blat2.ps1 it bugs me
Arg0: it
Arg1: bugs
Arg2: me
```

**Just another twist to the issue:**

Another fact in this is that I cannot change the program that calls Blat2.exe or how it passes parameters to blat2.exe.

A typical command line would be

```
     blat2.exe -t something  anotherthing
```

So the expected parameters would be

```
-t
something 
anotherthing
```

My issue is that I can get the $args to show up if it is is PS1 run, but after compiling they quit showing up.  It's like the compile is preventing the program from accepting the parameters.

Being a newbie, I'm pretty sure I am making a rookie mistake.

Why does the EXE version not  recognize the incoming parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in eventviewer? Have you tried running the full path of the executable? C:\path\to\executable.exe arg1 arg2 arg3

Comment: I checked the event log.  No errors reported.   In running using the full path, it did not behave any differently.

Comment: I found documentation that says when you convert the PS1 to an EXE that you have to include the -arguments .  I can get it to work if I do the .\blat2.exe -arguments -t something  anotherthing  .  However the software program that is calling the exe cannot be modified to add the -arguments into the call.   Is there anyway to get the exe to recoginze the parameters without the -arguments?

Comment: Here is a solution that worked for me.   First, it turns out that when you compile the PS1 to and EXE that the only way to get the EXE to accept the parameters is to use a -arguments option.   So the call would look something like this.                                 blat2.exe -aruguments -t something  anotherthing     Since this would not work in my environment (I have no control over the program calling blat2.exe) this solution would not work.

Comment: I credit Qlemo on experts exchange with this solution using a reference to the environmental variable.                                         $ownarg = [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()
& cmd.exe /C "C:\TEST\Blat2.exe"  $ownarg[1..$ownarg.Count]                   This pulls in the command line that was sent, which is all I wanted.  It mimcs the %* in dos.   Then I call the program passing the $ownarg skipping the first parameter.  This contains the reference to the program that is being called and those that are familiar with DOS, it is like the PO - first parameter value.

Comment: I did not need to pass that along.    When complied, this works great.

Answer (score 0):

Please see that last postings for the complete explanation of the  solution that worked for me.

In a nutshell:

```
$ownarg = [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()

& cmd.exe /C "C:\TEST\Blat2.exe" $ownarg[1..$ownarg.Count]
```

Answer (score 0):

i've made an exe using [this](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=op2e) utility

Call: test.exe param1 param2 param3

**Output**

`Arg0: param1
Arg1: param2
Arg2: param3`

Call: PS C:\ .\test.exe it bugs me

**Output**

`Arg0: it
Arg1: bugs
Arg2: me`